# Unable to style h1 tag and its contents

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

```
 <% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
 <div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
     <h1>
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <%= @user.name %>
     </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
 </div>
```

My .html.erb is given above as follows, I'm trying to style the @user.name variable under h1 tag but I'm unable to do so. When I inspect element I'm able to style everything under the h1 tag directly but no luck trying with my actual css file.

```
 aside {
 h1 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: left;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-top: 0px;
 }
}
```

Comment: are you using scss?

Comment: @solias please define css as below

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes.

Comment: @Solias is your latest changes reflected in your css file first check it out

Comment: @Rahul It is. I called .gravatar class directly for some other purposes and the css worked just fine.

Comment: try adding `body h1{ color: red!important; }  ` and see if it works

Comment: Yes it does. But I don't want to edit all the h1 tags, just this one pertaining to the <aside> tag

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check now.

```css
aside h1{
 

     font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: left;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
     <h1>
      Header
     </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
 </div>
```

Comment: turns out the CSS is just fine. I just made a silly mistake while working on another branch. As I switched I realized I hadn't saved my show.html.erb file  and that's why it wasn't even recognizing the CSS changes. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Using**

```
.user_info h1{

  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: left;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-top: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work. and you accidentally added an extra { there

Comment: Yes, so Update my answer.

Comment: I meant the updated version itself doesn't work. for some reason i can't call h1 tag via the aside tag at all. Is there another way to reference it?

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you

```
aside h1{
  color: red!important;
}
```

hoewever I dont recommend using `important` but in your case we need to debug your code and apply css precedence accordingly

meanwhile you can try below code and see if it works for you

```
body aside .user-info h1{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: @solias there might be other css overriding your css so you need to debug if not works but by applying `important` it will work for you